# app rejection in app store issues?

Tags: ios, iphone

We noticed that your app requires users to register with personal information that is not directly relevant to your app’s core functionality. Specifically, the following fields are required but do not appear to be directly relevant to your app’s core functionality:

-Telephone number

Comment: Well that is a clear description, make the phonenumber optional and resubmit your app. 

Next time also include your question and not just the rejection message.

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple Guideline, you can't force user to add personal information like email and telephone. You can only force when those things are your core features. Like if user can register with Mobile only then you can keep it mandatory and force user to enter.

Comment: we giving region why will asking for phone number but they asking reprated this one

Comment: If your reason is valid, then definitely they will allow. There are many application in store for which we have login with Mobile number and for them Mobile number is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is very strict about user sensitive data and its security architecture. If you are asking user to enter his/her personal details then your apps core functionality should use this information in order to use your app. If you are not using this information then simply don't ask user or if you are using for particular reason then reply to Apple about your scenario where you are going  to require users details. Hope this clarifies your doubts.